# How to get the values from html form into ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am doing a project in django which is a car rental/sale web app, the search query works, but when i am trying to submit my form in ajax it seems like it never reaches into ajax.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-header bg-info text-white">
        <h4>
            <i class="fas fa-car"></i> Search Car </h4>
    </div>
    <form method="get" id="search-form">
        <div class="input-field">
            <label for="from">Number:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="from-place" placeholder="Any" name="number" />
        </div>
        <section>
            <label for="class">Car Type:</label>
            <select class="cs-select cs-skin-border input-half">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Any</option>
                <option value="1">Sedan</option>
                <option value="2">Saloon</option>
            </select>
        </section>
        <section>
            <label for="class">Price:</label>
            <div class="wide">
                <select class="cs-select cs-select-half cs-skin-border input-half" name="price">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>any</option>
                    <option value="1000">1.000</option>
                    <option value="2000">2.000</option>
                    <option value="3000">3.000</option>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <input type="hidden" name="search_filter" value="true">
            <input type="submit" id="search-apa" value="Search">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and this ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var searchText = $('#search-form').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/cars/search_car/?search_filter=' + searchText,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(resp) {
                var newHtml = resp.data.map(d => {
                    return `<div class="cars">
                        <a href="/cars/${d.id}">
                        <h4>${d.type}</h4>
                        <p>${d.price}</p>
                    </a>
                    </div>`
                });
                $('.cars-index').html(newHtml.join(''));
                $('.search-form').val( '');
            },
            error: function(xhr, ststus, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })

    });
});
```

I am trying to get the values from the form into ajax, but when i click search it says undefined. I printed `searchText` and i does not print anything, it seems like it never reaches the ajax, is something wrong with my form or my i am not calling properly in ajax?
The error that shows is

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
search_car.js:25 Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Looks like `searchText` should be set to `$('[name=search_filter]').val()` or something other than `$('#search-form').val()` (like the first suggested answer, if you're intending to send all form inputs). Also, doesn't look like your Price `select` closes.

Comment: @mark.hch i tried your version for the searchText and it prints true, when i actually need the values. car id is undefined therefore i cant navigate to the car.

Comment: Yea, I didn't actually check the element type or embedded value (being `hidden` and `true` respectively), I just saw the name and guessed (if I was posting an answer vs. a comment I may have taken more time to read) - which is why I said `or something other than $('#search-form').val()`. Sending `true` alone certainly doesn't help, but you accepted the answer I was referencing with `(like the first suggested answer ...)`, so looks like all is good. See ya around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$('#search-form')` doesn't have any value, because it's a form. You need the `<input />`'s value. If you need to send the whole form's data, you need to use:

```
data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
```

In your AJAX call, please change this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/cars/search_car/?search_filter=' + searchText,
                type: 'GET',
                data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
                success: function(resp) {
                var newHtml = resp.data.map(d => {
                    return `<div class="cars">
                        <a href="/cars/${d.id}">
                        <h4>${d.type}</h4>
                        <p>${d.price}</p>
                    </a>
                    </div>`
                });
                $('.cars-index').html(newHtml.join(''));
                $('.search-form').val( '');
            },
            error: function(xhr, ststus, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })

    });
});
```

And make sure you have `name` attribute for everything and it gets matched in the backend too.

Comment: I don't get the car id, so I cant navigate to the car.

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori I didn't understand. Can you explain please?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's wrong with the code is this `var searchText = $('#search-form').val();`
You should get the value of each field by their own selector, you can not just get all the values from form with the form selector. Try console logging the `searchText` and see if it actually has any value

Comment: Just FYI - OP did state `I printed  searchText and i[t] does not print anything` - so you're definitely correct.

Comment: Yea, that is the issue there, try `yourInputName.val()` for whatever field you are trying to search.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing form value with. Val()  function. Which is incorrect As form contains multiple child elements it won't return you a value. If you have to access search text then it must be an input control like  $('#from-place').val().

Answer (score -1):

The line

```
var searchText = $('#search-form').val();
```

asigns searchText an empty string value. What you want is:

```
let formString = $("#search-form").serialize();
```

Comment: Might it have something to do with the fact that you are using a GET method for submitting a form, instead of a POST?